# Resources.Load returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following structure `Assets -> Resources -> Levels.json` I then run the following method:

```
void LoadLevel(int level){
    TextAsset json = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Levels.json");
    print(json);
    Levels.CreateFromJSON(json.text);
}
```

And what happens, is that `json` is `null`, and I am not sure why... I have looked at other examples and it looks like I am doing it right...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null. Only objects of type will be returned if this parameter is supplied. The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project, **extensions must be omitted.**

Remove .json.

Comment: Five years later and this helped me a lot. Simple and correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: glad it helped!